# How do I build ImageMagick with OpenCL?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, makefile, imagemagick, opencl

I have the latest Ubuntu LTS and Intel OpenCL drivers for it. I need to build ImageMagick library so it would have OpenCL enabled but I cant figure out how to do this. I'd like to build it from the source so that I could tinker on it myself.

I got ImageMagick 7.0 from [the official mirror at GitHub](https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick). Support for OpenCL is stated on the website of the library, but unfortunately the documentation is very scattered and intricate.

I built the library with `./configure` (no args) and `make` `make install`. Surely no support for OpenCL was provided as prompted by `convert -version`. For the sake of an experiment, i wrote a C++ program that calls `image.blur(6, 1.5)`. Before the library's building, I put into the `BlurImage()` funciton in [MagickCore\effect.c](https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/blob/master/MagickCore/effect.c) a small snippet that creates a file and prompt some string into it.

I got both blurred image and a file issued, so the library seems to work. Now I need to build it with OpenCL.

I executed `./configure --enable-opencl LIBS=-ldl`. When I built the library form this execution, `convert -version` promted an OpenCL support.

As far as I learned the source of ImageMagick, the OpenCL kernels are kept in [MagickCore\accelerate-private.h](https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/blob/master/MagickCore/accelerate-private.h) and compiled runtime. Actual code in C that calls accelerated functions is stored in [MagickCore\accelerate.c](https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/blob/master/MagickCore/accelerate.c). I made the same moves, and put that file creation snippet into `AccelerateBlurImage()` function. I got the blurred image, but no file was created so this function was never called even though OpenCL feature is stated.

The wierd thing I've noticed is that none of none of accelerated counterparts of the effect functions are actually called anyplace else. So I can't actullay realise how OpenCL-supporting functions are used.

Another wierd thing I've noticed is the result from `diff Makefile_without_OpenCL Makefile_with_OpenCL`. `Makefile_without_OpenCL` is the `Makefile` created by `./configure` command, `Makefile_with_OpenCL` is the `Makefile` created by `./configure --enable-OpenCL LIBS=-ldl`. The result shows that the latter file additionally includes `-pthread` flag and `-ldl` lib, but nothing actually related to OpenCL is used.

Do I get something wrong and OpenCL is already in use, even though `AccelerateBlurImage()` funciton is not called? If that's not the case, what is the correct flow in order to build ImageMagick with OpenCL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you enable OpenCL in ImageMagick this does not mean that it will be used. The first time one of the *accelerated methods* is used there will be a performance test of your system. The result of this will be written to the file `ImagemagickOpenCLDeviceProfile` in `$HOME/.config/ImageMagick/` or `%LOCALAPPDATA%\.config\ImageMagick\`. The file contains multiple `device` nodes:

```xml
<device>
  <type>
    <name>Your card/CPU</name>
    <driver>1.0</driver>
    <score>3.9468</score>
  </type>
</device>
```

The device with the best (lowest) score wins and will be used. If your CPU is chosen as the best device then OpenCL will not be used. So when the *accelerated methods* are called they return quickly at the start of the method. These methods are called from within the *non accelerated method*. When the *accelerated method* is called there is a check to see if an OpenCL device is available. If a device is available the method will do the operation with OpenCL and return `true` as the result of the method. If `false` is returned the execution of the *non accelerated method* will continue and do the same thing as when the code is not linked with OpenCL.

The next time you use ImageMagick this file will be loaded from disk and the cached score is used to choose the best device. If you install a new video card / cpu or update the driver a new performance measurement will occur.

One of the options that uses OpenCL is `-despeckle` so you could force the performance measurement by executing the following command: `convert logo: -despeckle null:`

Comment: Good answer! Is there a quick/simple commandline invocation of IM that will cause an *"accelerated method"* to run and thereby create the file you refer to?

Comment: The first actual problem was is that I didn't know about the necessary Magick::EnableOpenCL(). Then the evaluation happened, and eventually my CPU was preferred over the GPU. As far as I understood, the evaluation process is described in MagickCore/opencl.c. Won't it be a trouble for you to clarify how the actual choise between accelerated and non-acceleratied functions is done when a funciton like `blur()` is called? I mean, how the evaluation is saved and actually affect further execution. Anyway, thank you very much, your answer moved me from dead point.

Comment: I have updated the answer, I hope this explains it better.

Comment: @dlemstra I just asked a similar question on ServerFault: [Why is ImageMagick with OpenCL slower than OpenMP?](http://serverfault.com/q/734854/83039) where I mention your answer here on SO. Maybe you can help?